Using a LiFePO4 battery as a large capacitor
I have an application where motors feed energy back. At the moment the motors are supplied directly by a battery. I want to supply the motors instead with a DC/DC converter. The motors feed back so much energy that the output capacitors of the DC/DC converter would blow up. I don't to waste the energy. Adding large capacitors in parallel to the motors is not really an option. Capacitors of the required size are not really available. Available options are extremely expensive. Hence, the idea is to use a battery as a large capacitor. I successfully did an experiment to check that the system voltage doesn't increase too much.
Now my question. With the above solution, the SoC of the battery stays basically at the same level throughout operation. This is because it remains at the output voltage of the DC/DC converter plus/minus a tiny voltage difference. Is this an issue when using a LiFePO4 battery?

You haven't given any working details of the experiment or solution so, how can anyone answer your question?

LiFePO4 batteries tend to have a flat discharge curve.  The voltage doesn’t change significantly over a wide range of SoC levels.

What makes you think the state of charge stays constant? Based on the information provided, the SOC increases with regeneration. If the SOC were to remain constant, the same amount of energy from the regeneration would need to be dissipated elsewhere. Not the battery.

can you add a series diode?

@Andyaka I didn't?

@liaifat85 yes, this is what I am counting on with this approach.

@MOSFET whenever the motors feed energy back, the bus voltage increases a bit and rises above the configured output voltage of the DC/DC converter. The DC/DC converter will stop pumping energy into its output capacitors or do so at a lower rate. When the motors use energy again, the voltage will drop again to the nominal output voltage of the DC/DC converter. In any case, every DC/DC converter has a ripple of its output voltage based on the capacitors used in the output stage. The battery is just another capacitor acting in parallel for that matter. Does that make sense?

@dandavis how would that help?

@FelixCrazzolara Well what's powering the DC/DC convertor? You say "At the moment the motors are supplied directly by a battery" Does this imply you will no longer have a battery as a power source? If not, what is the power source?

a series diode would prevent the motor from feeding back to the source.

To deal with regenerative energy you basically have two choices (as you noted):

Dissipate the energy.  Usually, a resistor bank with some sort of comparator and switch to switch in the load when the bus voltage rises above a set level.

Store or use the energy. This can be a capacitor bank, though this has limitations. A battery or regenerating the energy back into the AC grid (if available) is also possible.


If you use a battery, you still have to comply with the charge and discharge specs.  You need a charge controller. LiFePO4 batteries are more tolerant than other types, but you can't just continue to dump energy into the battery safely.
What happens when the battery is full, and you need to regenerate?  You typically need a safety backup resistor bank to dissipate the energy. I'm not sure how you propose to guarantee that the SOC of the battery stays constant throughout operation?

As I wrote in another comment, the voltage of the battery stays constant because its kept that way because all energy is actually provided by the DC/DC converter and the battery acts just as a buffer inbetween. Thank you for your answer. My question was actually not so much about how to deal with the regenerative energy. Instead, I am wondering whether the battery chemistry can deal with the fact that the battery SoC remains roughly constant. I have not heard of a battery application yet, where the SoC stays roughly at the same level always.

Well, if all energy is provided by the DC-DC converter, and none from the battery, every regen event will increase the SOC of the battery, no? I still don't understand how the battery SOC stays fixed.  However, if it somehow does, keeping the SOC of the battery between 40% and 60% will give the longest service life.  A fully charged or fully discharged Li battery won't give the maximum lifetime.  Li batteries don't need full charge/discharge cycles to maintain capacity like NiCd batteries did.
